# Problem with using multiple textures on a multi uv mapped object (cycles)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing

I'm trying the texture my character, but I'm having a lot of trouble mapping all of my textures together, I have been researching a lot but I couldnt find anything that could help me!

I have this character here, that I textured by creating uv maps for 5 body parts like head, body, arms and legs, and assigning materials to selected faces.
Like, If I made a UV map for the head, I made a material and assigned the material to the faces the UV map is created from.

And my character looks like that

[image]

Problem is, assigning the materials to the faces takes away my freedom to use the same faces again in case I want to texture parts of the body and parts of the legs on a different material (I want to paint around the legs and body to cover up the wierd thing going on if you pay enough attention to it)

So my idea is that instead of assigning materials to the faces, I could instead only assign the textures to their UV MAP.

My UV maps are set up like this:
[image]

Now after doing some research, people say its possible to achieve putting a bunch of textures doing it with this setup of nodes:

[image]

Unfortunately when I do that, that what happens in result:

[image]

Basically what you see here is both the head texture and the arms texture overlapping each other, and when I apply only one texture, lets say, the head, that what happens in exchange:

[image]

As the texture goes outside of the assigned UV map.

I tried using attribute instead, using texture coordinate, mapping node, using two materials for separate textures, seaming the head, nothing!

I hope you can help me with this! nothing I could find over the web!

Comment: Why create so many UV maps? Why not just one map with one texture for the character?

Comment: Because its a complex character, mapping the entire character makes texturing terrible because of resolution, I would have to apply a really really large image so that nothing would be pixelated, also my machine lacks the computing power to paint and draw over such huge canvases.
Making a bunch of UV Maps makes the task easier to work with.

Comment: I know I could work with smaller canvases but detail is important to me and I hope you understand my choice to work with different UV maps. I also don't want to split my object into different parts